# I lost the ability to connect with ssh from master to slaves (AWS EC2 Hadoop)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, ssh, amazon-ec2

I recently lost the ability to connect my master via ssh to my slaves and secondary namenode.

I have 4 EC2 instances on which I have a hadoop cluster (one NameNode, one secondary nameNode, and 2 slaves).

I'm still able to make ssh connection with putty, but then I can't realise the ssh connection as follow : ssh ubuntu@instanceDns.
I have the following error :

> Permission denied (publickey).

I'm sure i didn't change anything toward the ssh connection so I'm little bit surprised.
Here is a screen of a verbose tentative of a ssh connection.
[image]

I noticed that I don't have id_rsa, id_rsa-cert and the other anymore in my .ssh file. I guess they were here before but I don't know they could disapear like this.

WHy is this happening ?
Is there a solution to get the ssh connection between my machine available again ?

Comment: Just out of interest is there any reason not to be using EMR

Comment: yes I wanted to learn how to deploy hadoop on distributed cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any private key (ssh would know about) to authenticate to these servers.

- Locate where is the private authentication key
- configure OpenSSH to use it in `~/.ssh/config`

or

- Convert the existing PuTTY key to OpenSSH format
- configure OpenSSH to use it in `~/.ssh/config`